# Изучение GWT для разработки игр

Tags: java, разработка-игр, gwt

Доброго времени суток!

Есть задача овладеть GWT для разработки игр. Что и как Вы бы посоветовали изучать?

И ещё вопрос. Сколько времени займет освоение фреймворка, если тратить по 4-5 часов в день? Есть знания по основам явы.

Comment: Смотря какие игры. Что-то я не помню gwt виджетов для динамических картинок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет!
Могу посоветовать раздел на хабре [Google Web Toolkit](http://habrahabr.ru/hub/gwt/) (игра [сапер на GWT](http://habrahabr.ru/post/76043/)).
Также основная инфа - [Google Web Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/).
Что касается времени, которое необходимо для изучения, то это дело довольно таки щепетильное. Вы можете изучить за день - два, а может и за месяц, все зависит от Вас, точно никто не скажет. То, что знаете Java это только +. Дерзайте. Ищите примеры разработки, изучайте их, экспериментируйте.